# How to start a ReactJS app with HTTPS instead of HTTP in dev

Tags: reactjs, https

I have a ReactJS app I need to start using HTTPS instead of HTTP in development. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, nodejs v 12.22.1 and npm v 6.14.12.

According to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ I tried starting the app with: `HTTPS=true&&npm start` `HTTPS=true npm start`. Also created a .env file and set `HTTPS=true`.

And finally I eddited the package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"
}
```

But nothing seems to work. It keeps deploying as HTTP... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a linux distro, you should try [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/#linux-macos-bash) command.

See CRA's official [page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/) on using HTTPS in dev environment.

Comment: I did this, but it does not work either. Thanks anyway.